# why is it that $1 \in m?$ why not $1 \in m+xy?$

Tags: commutative-algebra

I  have some confusion on Atiyah commutative algebra

**Proposition $1.9$**. If $x \in\mathfrak R \implies  1-xy $ is a unit in $A$ for all $y \in A$.

It is written that   Suppose  $1-xy$ is not unit. By $(1.5)$  it belong to some maximal  ideal $m$  but $x \in \mathfrak R \subseteq m$, hence $xy \in m$  and therefore $1 \in m$.

**My confusion** : Im not  getting why is it that $1 \in m?$ why not $1 \in m+xy?$

**My thinking**: I think $m \subseteq \mathfrak R$. Here $1-xy$ is not unit. Now by using the theorem  ''each proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal'' $\implies 1-xy \in m \implies 1 \in m+xy$.

Also, $xy \neq m$ and  $x \in \mathfrak R$ and $y \in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1-xy\in m$ and $xy\in m$ and $m$ is an Ideal therefore $1=(1-xy) +xy \in m+m =m .$

Comment: I think $xy \in A$  not $ m$ because  $y \in A$

Comment: If $m$ is an ideal  in $A$ then for all $x\in m , y\in A $ we have $xy\in m.$

Comment: okay @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura